# Using Visual Studio Code HTML features in template languages

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, intellisense

[Visual Studio Code supports rich prettify and formatting options for HTML](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_formatting). Advanced HTML editing features include Intellisense, CSS class auto-completion and so on.

How these features could be enabled for HTML producing template languages, including but not limited to

- Nunjucks .njk
- Jinja .jinja
- Handlebars
- Django

These languages are very similar to HTML, with some formatting tags embedded in. For example, on the Jetbrains products (IDEA, Webstorm, Pycharm) one can quite directly use advanced HTML options in these templates, even though those templates are not pure HTML.

[image]

I would assume there is some setting where specific file extensions can be tagged as "HTML like", which would allow sue the features.

Comment: I posted a great working solution here: [Visual Studio Code and Jinja templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72761998/9152905)